# How to make socket.recv(500) not stop a while loop

Tags: python, sockets, while-loop

I made an IRC bot which uses a while true loop to receive whatever is said.
To receive I use recv(500), but that stops the loop if there isn't anything to receive, but i need the loop to continue even if there isn't anything to receive.
I need a makeshift timer to continue running.

Example code:

```
/A lot of stuff/
timer=0
while 1:
    timer=timer+1
    line=s.recv(500) #If there is nothing to receive, the loop and thus the timer stop.
/A lot of stuff/
```

So either I need a way to stop it stopping the loop, or I need a better timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [settimeout](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html?highlight=socket.send#socket.socket.settimeout) on the socket so that the call returns promptly (with a suitable [exception](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html?highlight=socket.send#socket.timeout), so you'll need a try/except around it) if nothing's there -- a timeout of 0.1 seconds actually works better than non-blocking sockets in most conditions.

Comment: +1 not that bad an idea.  I prefer select because it can be extended to multiple sockets, but a timeout on the socket is a fair solution to the OP question.

Comment: @Heath, `select` is way better (and `epoll` better still &c) -- but, I generally prefer to answer questions even when I know that daring to answer a question (correctly) will subject me to a barrage of downvotes from the Politically Correct (as it did in this case) -- being maxed out for the day means I don't get credit for upvotes but still get dinged for downvotes (yeah, SO _is_ crazy that way!-), so a rep-maximizer would of course shut up on maxing out for the day, but I still prefer being useful to people over maximizing my rep!-).

Answer (score 1):

This is going to prove a bad way to design a network application. I recommend looking into [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/), a networking library with an excellent implementation of the IRC protocol for making a client (like your bot) in `twisted.words.protocols.irc`.

http://www.habnabit.org/twistedex.html is an example of a very basic IRC bot written using twisted. With very little code, you are able to access a whole, correct, efficient, reconnecting implementation of IRC.

If you are intent on writing this from a socket level yourself, I still recommend studying a networking library like twisted to learn about how to effectively implement network apps. Your current technique will prove less effective than desired.

Comment: I want to make the bot from scratch like I said before. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You should reconsider that goal. That is not the best approach to make a good IRC bot nor is it the best approach to learn sockets.

Comment: Why should it be a good irc bot?
Its my first "real" python project.
And I am doing it for fun. Solving problems that arise because I don't use libs is fun.

Comment: I presumed you may have wanted it to be a good IRC bot because I know I personally do not like writing bad software (and left room for that not being your goal!). 

Further, I didn't insist you use twisted—I predicted before you said so that you might insist on using socket (a different library!) instead. What I really recommended against is your current approach to implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use [`irclib`](http://python-irclib.sourceforge.net/) which takes care of this sort of detail for you.

Comment: When I made the bot I decided I wanted to try to make it from "scratch".

Comment: That's fair. Having said that, you could have a look at the `irclib` source, it's not too long and doesn't have such a complex framework as Twisted, so it's a good place to pick up ideas.

Comment: @ImTooStupidForThis, implementing protocols at a socket level is hard and tedious if done right, which is one reason it is so seldom done right. If you have not studied other implementations of a protocol similar to IRC, you should really do so before trying to implement such a framework yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with low-level python, consider using the `ready_sockets = select.select([s.fileno()], [], [], 0.1)` -- this will test the socket `s` for readability.  If your socket's file number is not returned in `ready_sockets`, then there is no data to read.

Be careful not to use the timout of "0" if you are going to call select repeatedly in a loop that does not otherwise yield the CPU -- that would consume 100% of the CPU as the loop executes.  I gave 0.1 seconds timeout as an example; in this case, your timer variable would be counting tenths of a second.

Here's an example:

```
timer=0    
sockets_to_check = [s.fileno()]

while 1:
    ready_sockets = select.select(sockets_to_check, [], sockets_to_check, 0.1)
    if (len(ready_sockets[2]) > 0):
        # Handle socket error or closed connection here -- our socket appeared
        # in the 'exceptional sockets' return value so something has happened to 
        # it.
    elif (len(ready_sockets[0]) > 0):
        line = s.recv(500)
    else:
        timer=timer+1  # Note that timer is not incremented if the select did not
                       # incur a full 0.1 second delay.  Although we may have just
                       # waited for 0.09999 seconds without accounting for that.  If
                       # your timer must be perfect, you will need to implement it
                       # differently.  If it is used only for time-out testing, this 
                       # is fine.
```

Note that the above code takes advantage of the fact that your input lists contain only one socket.  If you were to use this approach with multiple sockets, which `select.select` does support, the `len(ready_sockets[x]) > 0` test would not reveal *which* socket is ready for reading or has an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the example but someone already helped me with something a bit simpler.
Thanks a lot though.

Comment: Yep, the "0.1 timeout" idea is indeed good (I suggest that on my answer too, albeit w/`settimeout`) -- nonblocking sockets, and equivalently 0-timeouts, can have bad performance impacts.

Comment: `if len(foo) > 0` is typically spelled `if foo`.

Comment: @Mike Graham: Typically not by me.  I guess it's a subjective comment.

Comment: @ImTooStupidForThis: No worries.  But you do owe both myself and Alex a +1 vote.  Especially me, since I modified my answer for you, not as much him, since you already gave him a check mark.